# How to put Epilog in ArrayPlot based on value at the position

Tags: plotting, graphics

Suppose I have data like this

```
 data={{"300+", "300+", "300+", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
  "Missing", "Missing", "Missing"}, {"300+", "300+", "0-50", "300+", 
  "51-100", "0-50", "101-200", "0-50", "0-50", "Missing"}, {"300+", 
  "201-300", "0-50", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
  "Missing", "Missing", "300+"}, {"300+", "51-100", "0-50", "101-200",
   "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", "201-300"}, {"300+", 
  "201-300", "0-50", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
  "Missing", "Missing", "Missing"}, {"300+", "0-50", "0-50", "51-100",
   "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", "Missing"}, {"300+", 
  "51-100", "0-50", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
  "Missing", "Missing", "101-200"}, {"300+", "0-50", "0-50", "51-100",
   "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", "101-200"}, {"300+", 
  "101-200", "0-50", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
  "Missing", "Missing", "Missing"}, {"300+", "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", 
  "0-50", "0-50", "0-50", "Missing", "0-50", "Missing"}};
```

And I want to make a grid as follows:

```
ArrayPlot[
   data, ColorRules -> {
            "0-50" -> GrayLevel[0.8],
            "51-100" -> GrayLevel[0.6],
            "101-200" -> GrayLevel[0.4],
            "201-300" -> GrayLevel[0.2],
            "300+" -> GrayLevel[0.],
            "Missing" -> GrayLevel[1]
         },
   ColorFunction -> Automatic, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large
]
```

I want to place symbols in the corresponding boxes based on the following rule:

```
{"0-50" -> ♜, "51-100" -> ♞, "101-200" -> ♝, 
 "201-300" -> ♛, "300+" -> ♚, "Missing" -> ""}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
labeling = {"0-50" -> ♜, "51-100" -> ♞,  "101-200" -> ♝, "201-300" -> ♛, 
      "300+" -> ♚, "Missing" -> ""};
epilog = Join @@ MapIndexed[Inset[#, #2 - 1/2]&, Transpose[Reverse@data /. labeling], {2}]
ArrayPlot[data, ColorRules -> {"0-50" -> GrayLevel[0.8], "51-100" -> GrayLevel[0.6], 
      "101-200" -> GrayLevel[0.3999999999999999], 
      "201-300" -> GrayLevel[0.19999999999999996`], 
      "300+" -> GrayLevel[0.], "Missing" -> GrayLevel[1]}, 
  ColorFunction -> Automatic, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> Large, Epilog -> {Red, FontSize -> 20, epilog}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think the position is still incorrect it need to be rotated 90 degree clockwise. Can you please make the changes as i still don't fully understand how it works.

Comment: @user13892, corrected the positions.